# Correlation of subsets of two sets of data

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics, subset, correlation

For instance, I have:

```
data1 = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}};
data2 = {{3, 2, 1}, {6, 7, 8}, {5, 4, 3}};
```

I want to calculate the correlation that `data1[[1, All]]` has with each subset of `data2`, then automatically perform the same calculation for `data1[[2, All]]` and `data1[[3, All]]`. Each set of data I am working with has the same number of subsets as the others.

I have tried:

```
numsubsets = Table[i, {i, Length[data1]}]
Correlation[data1[[#, All]], data2[[#, All]]] & /@ numsubsets
```

but this does not work as it only calculates the correlation of, for instance, `data1[[2, All]]` with `data2[[2, All]]` and not the correlation of `data1[[2, All]]` with `data2[[1, All]]` and `data2[[3, All]]`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `Outer[Correlation[#1, #2] &, data1, data2, 1]`

Comment: Thank you! I will test your code too.

Comment: Actually, even simpler: `Outer[Correlation, data1, data2, 1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps

```
data1 = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}};
data2 = {{3, 2, 1}, {6, 7, 8}, {5, 4, 3}};
Table[Map[Correlation[data1[[i, All]], #] &, data2], {i, Length[data1]}]
```

Please test this carefully

Comment: Thank you! I will test it and let you know how it works.

Comment: Choosing good example data so that it is almost certain to show whether the answer is correct or not would be very helpful. Including what the answer should provide as a result would be even more helpful. That will let people realize that they have made a mistake before posting.

Comment: I will make sure to do that with my next question. Thank you for providing such a concise answer, it worked perfectly and provided the type of output  I needed.